# Определение версии двоичного файла средствами Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, файлы

Мне необходимо определить версию двоичного файла (jar, dll, exe, тд) средствами Java.
Необходимо, чтобы решение было кроссплатформенным. Все решения, которые я и находил были платформозависимые. Может быть кто уже решал подобную задачу?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы программа, запущенная на линухе, определила версию dll виндовза? А в линухе такой функции не предусмотрно, чтобы определять версии фалов виндовза, потому что они нафиг ему не интересны. И наоборот. Так?

Comment: Не совсем. Я хочу чтоб один jar мог быть запущен как на Виндовс, так и на линукс, и в каждом случае мог определять версии файлов этой системы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться JNI. Вместе со своей программой на java разработать платформенные JNI dll-ки, реализующие Ваш API для java определения версий файлов. Вероятно это уже всё есть, раз сами утверждаете, что где-то что-то находили. Поставлять свою java-программу вместе с этими dll-ками.

```
public class JavaVersion {
    public native Version nativeVersion(String filename);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ("винмастдай".equals(System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name")) {
            System.load("version.dll");
        } else if ("линух".equals(System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name")) {
            System.load("version.so");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Утюг не той системы");
        }
        Version version = nativeVersion(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[0] + " версия " + version);
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть ещё прожект JNA - Java Native Access. Вроде как попроще чем JNI. Например чтобы вызвать функции ядра windows не написал ни одной строчки на С, всё в java

Answer (score 0):

Версию файла **.jar** можно определить, используя файл /META-INF/manifest.mf, включенный в архив

Приложения формата **.exe** имеют заголовок, описанный в этой статье:
http://wiki.osdev.org/PE#PE_header

Здесь версия приложения определена полями **mMajorImageVersion** и **mMinorImageVersion**, находящимися во вторичном заголовке (сразу за первичным).

Аналогично и с **.dll**

Comment: Если уж говорить о структурах от MS, лучше давать ссылку на их документацию: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Версия файла в виндовых свойствах к MinorImageVersion не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Но ведь даже MSDN говорит, что оба поля отвечают за "Image Version", т. е., за версию объекта (приложения, библиотеки), которому этот вторичный заголовок принадлежит

Comment: Говорить он может все что угодно, но к версии в свойствах файлов они отношения не имеют. К тому же формат версии в свойствах примерно такой:
Version:        1, 8, 71, 0
File version:   1, 8, 71, 0
В два поля это не лезет, да и поля при указанной выше информации все равно нулевые.

Answer (score 0):

Кросплатформенный способ - самому написать парсинг соответствующих структур файлов. Для MZPE (EXE, DLL и т.п.) интересующая вас информация хранится в секции ресурсов.